# Compact 4 Node Raspberry Pi 3 Cluster for Robots?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Can a Compact 4 Node Raspberry Pi 3 Cluster be enough powerful to elaborate videostreaming input data in real time for a drone?

Thank you for any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly depending on what you want to do, one [could be plenty powerful enough](http://bennycheung.github.io/raspberry-pi-3-for-computer-vision). I have done several projects using the Raspberry pi camera module and a single raspberry pi to do optical flow at several frames per second and had plenty of power left over to do other stuff.

But if you need it to go faster you could in theory split the processing over more than one raspberry pi by distributing the frames, but In reality I think the overhead of that would dominate unless processing was taking more than 1 second per frame. for the price of a 4 raspberry pi cluster (~\$190 after all the accessories and say at least 400g).

For that price and a lower weight you could get a much more powerful [Nvidia Jetson TK1](http://www.nvidia.com/object/jetson-tk1-embedded-dev-kit.html) (\$190 120g) which is powerful enough to apply deep neural networks, or stereo vision in real time and be much easier to use and develop with than some custom 4 raspberry pi solution